# Passing all data from s3 bucket to an s3 bucket with lambda function executed manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a month paritionated in day in an s3 bucket like:

```
2021/12/20/file.parquet
2021/12/19/file.parquet
2021/12/18/file.parquet
```

I want to create an AWS Lambda function to pass all the files in the day on the s3 bucket `2021/12`. So the function have to pass all the file from the day bucket to the month bucket.

So i want to move

```
2021/12/20/file.parquet to 2021/12/file.parquet
```

I  would like to do this with a lambda function that iterate all the path of the day and move the file in the path month, i will start the lambda manually

Comment: Is there an actual issue you’re struggling with? The approach would be to 1) list the items in the bucket. 2) copy each object to the new location 3) delete the old version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.